# Is there a way to get bash to let me move up directories by choosing highlighted directories in my prompt?

Tags: bash

I think using `cd ../..` to move up two directories is silly, so I was wondering if it's possible to configure bash to have an "up" command that lets me pick out which directory to move up to by using my arrow keys to select which directory in my prompt to move to.
Like this:

```
0: noah@noah-desktop: /home/noah/$ up
```

and then it would display this if I hit the left arrow key:

```
0: noah@noah-desktop: /home/noah/$
```

And this if I hit the left arrow key again:

```
0: noah@noah-desktop: /home/noah/$
```

And then when I hit enter it moves to that directory.
Is there a way to get it to do that? I can't seem to find any info on how to do this.

Comment: It's not possible. The prompt is not interactive.

Comment: With some clever scripting you could actually do this though it would be easier to do it at the input area rather than in the prompt itself. Though even easier than that would just be an `up` function that took a count or target path name.

Comment: Technically, clever scripting could include binding a key to a do-nothing function that just updates the environment with a new value of `PS1` and stores the name of the bolded directory, after which a new prompt is displayed. The impossible (or nearly so) part is updating a prompt which has already been drawn on the screen.

Comment: Hah, nice. I hadn't thought about actually *using* PS1 I was just going to manually move the cursor around to redraw text. But yes, using an entirely unmodified prompt is going to be hard because finding the path in it is not the simplest operation (or even necessarily possible).

Comment: How is this even a programming question, as opposed to an end-user-support question?

Answer (score 1):

You could write an `up` function that took a count of directories to ascend.

```
up() {
    i=${1:-1}
    while ((i--)); do
        cd ..
    done
}
```

You could write a function that took a path component and ascended to there.

```
up() {
    local comps
    IFS=/ read -a comps <<<"$PWD"

    local c i
    for c in "${comps[@]}"; do
        if [ "$c" = "$1" ]; then
            break
        fi
        ((i+=1))
    done

    : ${i:=${#comps[@]}}
    cd "$(IFS=/; printf %s "${comps[*]:0:$i+1}")"
}
```

Used as `up component` to go to the `component` directory above the current directory.

With some fancier readline/termcap magic a version like what was originally asked for could be created but it would take a good bit more work I think.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite as sleek as what you're proposing, but I think it's conceptually similar.  Start by creating this alias:

```
alias up='cd $PWD/'
```

Now, when you want to go "up", type `up` (no spaces, and don't hit Return) and then all at once Control-Meta-e.  This will expand your current line to something like:

```
cd /home/noah/
```

Now you can use Meta-b to navigate back through your path, one word/directory at a time.  When you're at the desired point in your path where you want to change directories to, type Control-k to chop off the end of the path, then hit Return.

Alternatively, instead of Meta-b and Control-k, you could also just use the Delete key.

Comment: I like this approach because I feel like if I screw around with how the prompt is drawn then it will lead to annoying bugs (I already tried messing around with drawing over stuff and managed to successfully overwrite the current prompt, but it was pretty hard). This seems like it's nice and simple enough to work with **any** prompt. Maybe I could tweak it to be more interactive.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach.  It uses the keys "." and "a" in place of the up arrow and Return because those are tricky to deal with in bash (hopefully the actual keys aren't relevant to your goal).  Add this function to your ".bash_profile":

```
up() {
    d="$PWD"
    while true ; do
        echo "$d"
        read -s -n 1 c
        case "$c" in
            .)
                d=$(dirname "$d")
                ;;
            a)
                cd "$d"
                break
                ;;
            *)
                break
                ;;
        esac
    done
}
```

Now, to navigate directories type `up`.  This will print out the current directory and allow you to navigate up a directory by pressing ".".  Each time you press "." it will print out what the new directory will be if you commit.  To change to that directory and stop navigation, type "a".  To abort the directory change, press any other key.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just by an arrow key. But you could define an alias something like below to move two directories up and similarly others:

```
alias up="cd ../.."
```

and once done, just type up in shell.

```
Example:
sh-4.3$ pwd                                                            
/home/cg/root
sh-4.3$ alias up="cd ../.."
sh-4.3$ up
sh-4.3$pwd
/home
```